# Registered base address schemes are [https] error

Tags: wcf, web-services, iis-7.5

I am trying to publish a wcf web service on an iis server and have it use Windows Authentication. I'm getting an error when I even try to publish it so I haven't gotten far enough to get prompted for a username. I do have a SSL certificate and want to use ssl.

This is my error:

```
[InvalidOperationException: Could not find a base address that matches scheme http for the endpoint with binding BasicHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [https].]
   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.MakeAbsoluteUri(Uri relativeOrAbsoluteUri, Binding binding, UriSchemeKeyedCollection baseAddresses) +16604769
   System.ServiceModel.Description.ConfigLoader.LoadServiceDescription(ServiceHostBase host, ServiceDescription description, ServiceElement serviceElement, Action`1 addBaseAddress) +1082
   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.ApplyConfiguration() +156
   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.InitializeDescription(UriSchemeKeyedCollection baseAddresses) +215
   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost..ctor(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses) +475
   System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses) +43
   System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(String constructorString, Uri[] baseAddresses) +530
   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.CreateService(String normalizedVirtualPath) +1413
   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.ActivateService(String normalizedVirtualPath) +50
   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath) +1172

[ServiceActivationException: The service '/subservice/ISubService.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception message is: Could not find a base address that matches scheme http for the endpoint with binding BasicHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [https]..]
   System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +901424
   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +178638
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.OnAsyncHandlerCompletion(IAsyncResult ar) +136
```

I've researched this a hundred times but I have very little experience with publishing a service. I've worked with them once they are built just never published one.

This is my web.config that I've modified from another web.config where that publishes fine:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!-- For more information on using web.config transformation visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=125889 -->

<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpEndpointBinding">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <!-- Basic <security mode="Transport"> -->
            <!-- To use Basic auth, just comment Windows and use this, but you need to configure basic in IIS as well -->
            <!-- <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" /> -->
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>

      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="default">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <!-- Basic <security mode="Transport"> -->
            <!-- To use Basic auth, just comment Windows and use this -->
            <!-- <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" /> -->
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="restBehavior">          
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>      
    </behaviors>

    <services>
      <service name="subservice.ISubService">
        <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding"  bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpEndpointBinding" contract="subservice.ISubService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>

        <endpoint address="rest" binding="webHttpsBinding" bindingConfiguration="default" behaviorConfiguration="restBehavior" contract="subservice.ISubService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />                       
          </identity>
        </endpoint>

        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress = "https://[site]/subservice/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>

      </service>

    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using basicHttpBinding, use the basicHttpsBinding

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.basichttpsbinding.aspx

Comment: basicHttpsBinding is only as of version 4.5, this might not work for everyone.